# The form Entity type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Anyone has any idea how to add some custom options to an entity field type in a nice and clean way? e.g

```
->add('groups', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Groups',
                'multiple' => 'true',
                'query_builder' => function(GroupsRepository $er) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                                ->orderBy('g.name', 'ASC');
                        }))
```

Let's say that query builder returns "Group1", "Group2" and "Group3". What I want is to "inject" another option called "Any Group" for example.

Thanks,Stelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EntityType` is a child of the `ChoiceType`. So, you have access to the [same options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html).

```
->add('groups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Groups',
    'multiple' => 'true',
    'query_builder' => function(GroupsRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')->orderBy('g.name', 'ASC');
     },
     'empty_value' => 'Any group',
))
```

Comment: That covers the case where you only want one extra option. I wonder if there is a clean way of merging entity options with an arraycollection or something along those lines.

Comment: You can add all option defined by EntityType and its parents. But if you want more options for your specific need, you have to defined your own Type.

Comment: This one I did not see coming, but: _The option "default_value" does not exist_ so it seems it does not play well with multiple:true

Comment: It's not `default_value` but `empty_value`. I edit my response. :)

Comment: Unfortunately empty_values does not work when you're in a multiple = true scenario, so I will just go for a custom type or actually have a default "Any group" entry in the entity. Thanks for all the help Oliver.